# CPU Usage Issue

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I have read up on some of the other CPU usage questions here, but I'm stuck with why my code isn't working.

I have the code in a separate Class named "ComputerPerformance" from From1.

```
class
{
   private string cCpuUtilization;

   public void cpuUtilization()
   {
      try
      {
         PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
         cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
         cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
         cCpuUtilization = cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
      }
      catch(System.InvalidOperationException e)
      {
      }
   }

   public String getCPUUtilization()
   {
      return cCpuUtilization;
   }
}
```

The code runs fine, but I am getting nothing as an output...

**Update**

The code now looks like this:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "Private Bytes";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "Explorer";
cCpuUtilization = cpuCounter.NextValue().ToString() + "%";
```

My problem now is it is returning the value: 6.728499E+07% all the time...
Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Get rid of that try/catch block, and maybe you'll find out what's wrong.

Comment: I've just done that and it comes up with the error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occured in System.dll
Additional information: Failed to initialize because CounterName is missing.

Not sure what that means...

Comment: It means that the "CounterName" property is not set. Maybe look at the documentation. And don't _ever_ hide exceptions from yourself.

Comment: It means exactly what it says ... simply put you tried to do something that library does not allow. Consider researching the class and finding example usage. This message suggests to me that CounterName needs to be set by constructor or something early at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your update of why you get `6.728499E+07%`, well you are reading the memory `Private Bytes` usage not `CPU Usege`. So the number being returned is the number of private bytes used by explorer (about `67,284,990` bytes). If you don't want scientfic notation for those large numbers pass in a [number formatting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `ToString`

```
cCpuUtilization = cpuCounter.NextValue().ToString("N0") + " bytes"; //Should now print "67,284,990 bytes"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code runs fine, but I am getting nothing as an output...

No, the code *doesn't* run fine:

1. You're never being told about the error because of your exception handling.
2. If the code *runs fine* then it would produce output.

Your code explicitly ignores any error that results in an `InvalidOperationException`.  Exceptions are there for a reason, usually to tell you that there is something seriously wrong.  The only time you should use should ignore them is when you really, *really* don't care that an exception has occurred.

In your code you set `CategoryName` to indicate which group of counters you're looking at, but never set the `CounterName` property to specify *which* counter to use.  And in the case of the `Processor` group, since there are potentially multiple processors.

Next problem, the first result you get from `cpuCounter.Nextvalue()` is groing to be `0.0`.  Always.  The `NextValue` method gets a sample from the counter and compares it to the last sample to calculate an actual value.  Necessarily this requires two calls to `NextValue` with a delay between in order to get a valid result.  That delay should be at least a second.

Here's some code that fixes a few of the problems:

```
public class CPUTime : IDisposable
{
    private PerformanceCounter counter;
    private DateTime lastcheck;
    private float lastvalue;

    public float Value
    {
        get
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - lastcheck).TotalMilliseconds > 950)
            {
                lastvalue = counter.NextValue();
                lastcheck = DateTime.Now;
            }
            return lastvalue;
        }
    }

    public CPUTime()
    {
        counter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);
        counter.NextValue();
        lastcheck = DateTime.Now;
    }

    ~CPUTime()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (counter != null)
        {
            counter.Dispose();
            counter = null;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:0.00}%", Value);
    }
}
```

If that's not fast enough for you - it only updates once per second, after all - then you'll need to use the `GetSystemTimes` API call and do your own calculations.  It still needs two samples, but you can call it much more frequently and get reasonable results.